# Xcode 9 code sign error code 1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode9

I have tried cleaning my build folder, deleting the provisioning and certificates for the app, deleting derived data, and manually managing signing yet no matter what I do, I cannot get the build to archive. I get one erorr in xcode:

> /Users/jscotto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ionic-deep-links-cdaztiimhbiwroaimkxbkdasbvpy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ionic-deep-links.app: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
>   Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

I have no clue what could be causing this.